# POST Request Error (REST API - TALEND ESB)

Tags: api, rest, post, talend, esb

Im trying to send Data with the POST request (using POSTMANfor testing with the body) but the data is saved with NULL values and the id always = 0 (ID in MySQL DataBase with Auto-Increment option)
Help pls, ty
there is all pictures

[image: job]

[image: postmain]

[image: schema]

Comment: Please refrain from posting images of code and post the actual code. The links to the images might not exist in the future thus rendering the question mute for future people with the same question. It also makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: does your flow "addOrder contains the data ? if you insert a tLogRow between tRestRequest and "orders" dbOutput, do you see your data ?